# Do I need the Distribution Certificate in my Keystore when building with a Distribution Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, app-store

We're one step away from our first AppStore deployment. Unfortunately we have to deploy under our customer's account (to show the correct company name)

At the moment we do not have access to the account's provisioning portal. My question is:
I could ask my customer to generate a distribution provisioning profile and send the *.mobileprovision file to me. Then I would ask them to create an iTunes connect developer account for me. Would this be sufficient for me to build the App on my box and to deploy it in the AppStore?

Or do I need my customer's Distribution Cetrificate (especially the private key - which he might not want to give away)?

Thanks four your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need the certificate, private key as well as the mobileprovision file for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. i m pretty new to.. But i think to deploy ur app on appstore u need to have ur clients submission certificate and a distribution provisioning profile.

hope it helps somehow... regards.